# How does the "a" tag in html work with path levels

Tags: html, tags

I have this current URL for example `http://test.com/dir1/dir2/dir3/div4`, on this page i want a link that just adds /dir5 to the current tag so I will get `http://test.com/dir1/dir2/dir3/div4/dir5`. I know you can use

```
<a href="/dir5">dir5</a> or <a href="./dir5">dir5</a>
```

But these results are different a lot depending on the current URL path and sometimes doesn't make any sence to me. Is there a way I can easily add another directory to the path in the `<a>` tag or would I just have to write the full path name down in the `<a>` tag?

Comment: If you want to err on the safe, *very* safe side, just type the full path.

Answer (score 1):

Both of them are relative urls. However, they act differently:

The first one will go to the sub-folder called "dir5". For your example, it will go to `http://test.com/dir5`

The second one will go to the next subfolder (if any) called dir5. This depends whether you are in one folder or another. For `http://test.com/dir1/dir2/dir3/div4`, you will get to `http://test.com/dir1/dir2/dir3/div4/div5`, but for `http://test.com/dir1/dir2/` you will get to `http://test.com/dir1/dir2/dir5`.

You have to write the full thing if you want to go from any arbitrary folder to that one. So you can use an absolute url `<a href="http://test.com/dir1/dir2/dir3/div4/div5">Go</a>` or a relative one `<a href="/dir1/dir2/dir3/div4/div5">Go</a>`, both of them will work.

Comment: Actually, the first one is also relative. It's relative to the domain. An absolute URL example would be `<a href="http://www.example.com/dir5">This URL</a>`

Comment: Completely true. I was just digging about it and I'm changing it.

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="dir5/">click me</a>
```

Comment: using this on `http://test.com/dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4` will get me to `http://test.com/dir1/dir2/dir3/dir5` and not `http://test.com/dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4/dir5` when im at `http://test.com/dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4/` with the `/` added it does work (this also works for `<a href="./dir5">dir5</a>`

Comment: That is because .../dir4/dir5 isn't actually a directory - it's an item called dir5 inside dir4. If you want dir5 to be treated as a directory, you need dir5 to have a trailing slash. If your users accidentally type ../dir5, you can always 302-redirect them to ../dir5/

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution is to use the html base tag. More informations can be founded [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1889076/is-it-recommended-to-use-the-base-html-tag)